# Oracle - SQL - Nest Queries Vs Where Clase

Tags: oracle, join, nested

I have 3 tables

```
1. BIG   (~6 Million Records, indexed on ID1 and some other columns     , not partitioned        , on DB instance 1)
2. VBIG  (~6 Billion Records, indexed on ID2 and some other columns     , partition on DATE field, on DB instance 2)
3. VVBIG (> VBIG by 10-15%  , indexed on ID1, ID2 and some other columns, partition on DATE field, on DB instance 2)
```

For a given DATE and few other filter conditions, I am using data from these 3 table to run some processing. I have to decide between the 2 queries.

```
select /*+ ORDERED */ 
    column1, column2
from
    BIG, VBIG, VVBIG
where 
    BIG.ID1   = VVBIG.ID1    and
    VBIG.ID2  = VVBIG.ID2    and
    VBIG.DATE = VVBIG.DATE   and
    VBIG.DATE = '1-Jan-2015' and
    BIG.CL1   = 'XYZ'        and
    VVBIG.CL1 = 'ABC'
```

OR

```
select /*+ ORDERED */ 
    column1, column2
from
    (select /*+ parallel */ from BIG   
        where BIG.CL1    = 'XYZ'), 
    (select /*+ parallel */ from VBIG  
        where VBIG.DATE  = '1-Jan-2015'), 
    (select /*+ parallel */ from VVBIG 
        where VVBIG.DATE = '1-Jan-2015' and VVBIG.CL1 = 'ABC')
where 
    BIG.ID1   = VVBIG.ID1    and
    VBIG.ID2  = VVBIG.ID2    and
    VBIG.DATE = VVBIG.DATE   and
```

Not sure if oracle is playing tricks, or if it is the distributed DB architecture, but my explain plan changes randomly.

My tests with ***synthetic*** data shows better performance with option#2. 
Is there a way I can rest assured that this would be the correct choice?

Also my Performance DBA suggested of using

```
/*+ use_hash( BIG, VBIB, VVBIG ) full(BIG) full(VBIG) full(VVBIG)  */
```

instead of the ORDERED hint. Would it be advisable as I am getting a CARTESIAN JOIN MERGE with his suggested change.

Comment: Why use hints in the first place?  Is there something about the statistics on these objects or the settings of the database that leads the optimizer to choose a poor plan?  If so, have you investigated the root cause of that issue before resorting to hints?  Why are you specifying a parallel hint (I assume with a parallel degree) rather than letting Oracle choose the degree of parallelism?  What are the query plans?  What was your DBA's rationale for his suggestion?  Is the optimizer actually doing something other than a hash join?

Comment: What is the datatype of the VBIT.DATE and VVBIG.DATE columns? Because if they're DATEs (or TIMESTAMPs), the very, very first thing I'd do is turn those strings into dates (or timestamps) via `TO_DATE()` (or `TO_TIMESTAMP()`). That way, you're not relying on implicit conversions, and you give the optimizer correct information that it can use in its decision making.

Comment: I'd tend to go with the first query (simplicity), but remove the hint and also add in an additional predicate of `and VBIG.DATE = to_date('1-Jan-2015', 'dd-Mon-yyyy')`  (assuming that VBIG.DATE is of DATE datatype). Obviously, which one you go for depends on execution paths, and timings etc.

Comment: I think you should take advantage of partition pruning with second query by providing date in inline view; you should also need check on date as boniest suggested. also let oracle decide if to use merge or Hash join I think with partition pruning you vvbig table will become avg table.

Comment: @Boneist, you are correct. I just checked and the DATE fields in the VBIG and VVBIG tables are of date dataytypes, My actual query are explicitly casted. I am checking on the other comments too.

Comment: Some additional info on why I suggested adding the seemingly-redundant additional predicate: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/01/01/transitive-closure/ (plus, it may help to encourage partition pruning on the VBIG table, if that's not already happening. You'd need to check your explain plans.)